# tidying up scanned pistol grip to 3d print

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to model a pistol grip so I can make it more orthopaedic.
The trouble is when I try to work the mesh from the scan into a flat surface I am unable to get a flat plane surface to model the rest of it onto.
The scan doesnt have any 90* corners either.
thanks

Comment: You may need to model it in two half's then mirror it.